# WMI query response is writing to file

Tags: c#, wmi, streamwriter

I am unable to write the response of a WMI query to file but I can print it to console.

I rewrote the query to use different WMI methods to pull the data. I changed back to the below method of ease of use.

I changed from `mo["PackageName"]` to `mo["PackageName"].ToString()` in case the response was not a writable string.

I googled - I have yet to find a similar issue and I am starting to think it is something obvious in my code that I am just overlooking.

```
//store log in same directory as exe is ran from
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(filepath);    
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT PackageName FROM Win32_Product WHERE PackageName LIKE 'jre%%'");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
   if (mo["PackageName"].ToString().Contains("jre"))
   {
      String packageName = mo["PackageName"].ToString();
      writeFile.WriteLine(host + "," + packageName);
   }
}
```

**update**
see my answer below:

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        {
            if (mo["PackageName"].ToString().Contains("jre"))
            {
                String packageName = mo["PackageName"].ToString();
                writeFile.WriteLine(host + "," + packageName);
                writeFile.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you declare writeFile, and what kinf of error/exception do you encounter?

Comment: Please post *all relevant code*. You have omitted what `writeFile` is and where it's defined.

Comment: i added the writer statement

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what `writeFile` is or how it's defined, I can only suggest that you use the easier `System.IO.File` class, like so:

```
File.AppendAllText(pathToYourFile, host + "," + packageName);
```

This will automatically open, write to, and close your file for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) for WMI query code creation.
It creates C# code and it is possible to test the queries.

Not a real answer - but might help.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to flush the writer after write.

```
String packageName = mo["PackageName"].ToString();
writeFile.WriteLine(host + "," + packageName);
writeFile.Flush();
```

Comment: You should still use `File.AppendAllText()` or another method inside the `File` class, it's much easier.

Comment: if i use appendallText i first have to use "File.WriteAllText" to create the file to write to. I only have 1 loop where i write to file and changing to appendalltext would cause me to rewrite my logic. unless appendalltext would also create a file if it is not already created.

Comment: That is not correct, AppendAllText creates the file for you. From the [File.AppendAllText() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx):  **If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.**

Comment: thanks SpikeX. I will give it another shot. When i tried using appendAllText it was not writing to file nor was it spitting out error messages. I will look further into it.

Comment: You should check your permissions to make sure the program has write access, also ensure that your path is correct and pointing to the right place, and that you aren't getting any exceptions from the operation.